# How to display next question in a label from an array of questions

Tags: swift, loops, if-statement, int, increment

[Screenshot of current code in simulator, once the next button is clicked nothing changes and the question presented in the label remains the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0eyT.png)

I am building a survey app and want to display a list of questions through a label. However, my current code functionality presents the same question and I need to go to the next question once a button is tapped. Once the button is tapped id like for the label to present the next question in the array and also move the previously asked question to the end of the array. Here is my current Swift code for the function that is called when the button is tapped, as of now it presents the same question when the button is tapped:

```
         func nextQuestion() {
    var questions = [choice1, choice2, choice3]
    var y = 0

    questionLbl.text = questions[y].question
    questions.remove(at: y)
    y += 1



    var button = UIButton()
    var tags = [0,1,2,3]

    for quest in questions {

    }

    for idx in tags {
        button = choiceButtons[idx]
        if idx < options.count {
            print("True! Index = \(idx) and options count = \(options.count)")
            button.setTitle(options[idx], for: .normal)

        }
        else {
            print("False! Index = \(idx) and options count = \(options.count)")

        }
    }

    print(questions)


}
```

Here's my object model that contains the objects that are used for the array of questions:

```
      import Foundation

   var choice1 = User.Choice(question: "How old are you?", opt1: "12", opt2: "11", opt3: "10", opt4: "23")
   var choice2 = User.Choice(question: "What color are you?", opt1: "Black", opt2: "White", opt3: "Purple", opt4: "Brown")
   var choice3 = User.Choice(question: "What day is it?", opt1: "Monday", opt2: "Tuesday", opt3: "Friday", opt4: "Sunday")



   var users = [User]()

   struct User {
var fields: Field
var choices = [Choice]()

struct Field {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var email: String

    init(first: String, last: String, email: String) {
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last
        self.email = email
    }
}

struct Choice {
    var question: String
    var opt1: String
    var opt2: String
    var opt3: String
    var opt4: String

    init(question:String, opt1: String, opt2: String, opt3: String, opt4: String) {
        self.question = question
        self.opt1 = opt1
        self.opt2 = opt2
        self.opt3 = opt3
        self.opt4 = opt4
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting y to 0 in your nextQuestion method, which resets the count everytime:

```
var y = 0

questionLbl.text = questions[y].question
questions.remove(at: y)
y += 1
```

So you're always getting the first question in the questions array. Also, I don't know why you're removing the first item from the questions array everytime, since you also recreate the array each time nextQuestion is called.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @andlin. What you said makes sense. Is there a certain way you would go about achieving my desired functionality?

Comment: Yes, make y a property of your viewcontroller (or wherever this code belongs) instead of local variable in the nextQuestion method. Do the same with questions array. There's no need to recreate everytime in nextQuestion. You also don't need to do this: questions.remove(at: y)

Comment: Got the code working with the desired functionality @andlin! Thanks again.